# Anyone have a JS zxing example that actually works?

Tags: javascript, qr-code, zxing

- @xzing/library 0.17.0
- node 12.13.1

I have had some success with jsQR and qrcode-reader but can't get zxing to work. Every image I throw at http://zxing.org it decodes which makes me believe that either the site isn't powered by zxing or uses an unreleased version.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const Jimp = require("jimp");
const { BinaryBitmap, RGBLuminanceSource, HybridBinarizer, DecodeHintType, MultiFormatReader, BarcodeFormat } = require('@zxing/library/esm5');

var qrFileData = fs.readFileSync("black_n_white.png");
Jimp.read(qrFileData, function(err, image) {
    if (err)
        return;

    zxingDecode(image);
});

function zxingDecode(image) {

    const hints = new Map();
    const formats = [BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE];
    const reader = new MultiFormatReader();

    hints.set(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS, formats);
    // hints.set(DecodeHintType.PURE_BARCODE, true); // Makes no difference with or without this
    // hints.set(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, true); // Shouldn't need this but either way makes no difference
    reader.setHints(hints);

    const luminanceSource = new RGBLuminanceSource(image.bitmap.width, image.bitmap.height, image.bitmap.data);
    const binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(luminanceSource));

    try {
        var result = reader.decode(binaryBitmap);
        console.log(result);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Zxing just plain doesn't work");
    }
}
```

Simple QR code, one of many I've tried...

[image]

I've even tried monchrome images with no success. I wrote my own Binarizer but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue which could be caused by the value of `image.bitmap.data.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT`: I get a value of 1 when it should be 4 for a luminance computation to occur. This is what I understand from the [zxing js code here](https://github.com/zxing-js/library/blob/v0.17.0/src/core/RGBLuminanceSource.ts#L70).

One solution here is to compute the luminances ourselves:

```
let luminances = [];
for (let p = 0; p < image.bitmap.width * image.bitmap.height * 4; p += 4) {
    const r = image.bitmap.data[p];
    const g = image.bitmap.data[p + 1];
    const b = image.bitmap.data[p + 2];

    const luminance = 0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b;

    luminances.push(luminance);
}
```

And then invoke the `RGBLuminanceSource` constructor like this (note the order of the parameters):

```
const luminanceSource = new RGBLuminanceSource(luminances, image.bitmap.width, image.bitmap.height);
```

Or we can convert the jimp output to the Int32Array type:

```
let pixels = [];

for (let p = 0; p < image.bitmap.width * image.bitmap.height * 4; p += 4) {
    const r = image.bitmap.data[p];
    const g = image.bitmap.data[p + 1];
    const b = image.bitmap.data[p + 2];
    const a = image.bitmap.data[p + 3];

    let rgba = r;
    rgba = (rgba << 8) + g;
    rgba = (rgba << 8) + b;
    rgba = (rgba << 8) + a;

    pixels.push(rgba);
}
```

And invoke the `RGBLuminanceSource` constructor like this (note the explicit conversion of the pixels to Int32Array):

```
const luminanceSource = new RGBLuminanceSource(Int32Array.from(pixels), image.bitmap.width, image.bitmap.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research, here is code that works on Node.js.

You need to install the `jimp` module first. https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp

```js
async function decodeQrCode(image) {
  const jimp = await Jimp.read(image);
  const { data: imageData, width, height } = jimp.bitmap;

  // convert to luminance
  const luminance = new Uint8ClampedArray(width * height);
  for (let i = 0; i < imageData.length; i += 4) {
    let r = imageData[i];
    let g = imageData[i + 1];
    let b = imageData[i + 2];
    let avg = (r + g + b) / 3;
    luminance[i / 4] = avg;
  }

  const luminanceSource = new RGBLuminanceSource(luminance, width, height);
  const binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(luminanceSource));

  const hints = new Map();
  const formats = [BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX];

  hints.set(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS, formats);
  hints.set(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, true);

  const reader = new MultiFormatReader();
  return reader.decode(binaryBitmap, hints);
}

console.log(await decodeQrCode(imageFile));
```